# How to update a date counter when starting activity

Tags: android

I've created an activity that counts days between the date you set and today and I'm trying to update the counter every time a user logs into the app, but it doesn't seem to work.

Below is my script, reflecting how I'm trying to achieve that:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.appactivity);
    DateDisplay=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.data);
    ContoGiorni=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewConto);
    update();
    updateConto();
}

protected void update(){

    SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences(DATA_PREFERENCIES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String giorno=prefs.getString(GIORNO,"00");
    String mese=prefs.getString(MESE,"00");
    String anno=prefs.getString(ANNO,"0000");
    DateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                .append(anno).append("-")
                .append(mese).append("-")
                .append(giorno)
    );
}

protected void updateConto(){

    SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences(DATA_PREFERENCIES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Calendar calendar=new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    long millisecondsToday=calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    String millisecond=prefs.getString(MILLISECOND,"0");
    long millisecondLong=Long.parseLong(millisecond);
    long diff = millisecondsToday - millisecondLong;
    long sec = diff / 1000 ;
    long minutes = sec / 60 ;
    long hr = minutes / 60 ;
    long days = hr / 24 ;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(CONTO,String.valueOf(days));
    String conto=prefs.getString(CONTO,"0");
    ContoGiorni.setText(
            new StringBuilder().append(conto).append(" giorni con te"));
}

public void setData (View v){

    showDialog(0);
}

protected DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences(DATA_PREFERENCIES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
        annoMio=year;
        meseMio=month;
        giornoMio=day;
        editor.putString(GIORNO, String.valueOf(annoMio));
        editor.putString(MESE,String.valueOf(meseMio+1));
        editor.putString(ANNO,String.valueOf(giornoMio));

        Calendar calOne=new GregorianCalendar();
        Calendar calTwo=new GregorianCalendar();
        calOne = Calendar.getInstance();
        calTwo = Calendar.getInstance();
        calTwo.set(annoMio, meseMio, giornoMio);
        long milliseconds1 = calOne.getTimeInMillis();
        long milliseconds2 = calTwo.getTimeInMillis();
        editor.putString(MILLISECOND,String.valueOf(milliseconds2));
        long diff = milliseconds1 - milliseconds2;
        long sec = diff / 1000 ;
        long minutes = sec / 60 ;
        long hr = minutes / 60 ;
        long days = hr / 24 ;
        editor.putString(CONTO,String.valueOf(days));

        editor.apply();
        update();
        updateConto();
    }
};
```

Where am I going wrong and how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In updateConto(), you're writing to SharedPreferences

> editor.putString(CONTO,String.valueOf(days))

but in the next line you fetch it

> String conto=prefs.getString(CONTO,"0")

without calling Editor#apply. So your changes to that preference never persist.